# How to calculate binomial sums using finite calculus

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

Sadly $\sum ^n _{k=0} \binom{a}{k}$ does not have a simple formula, but I thought you could maybe use $\sum ^n _{k=0} \binom{n}{k} = 2^n$ and the partial integration equivalent to find sums like $\sum ^n _{k=0} k\binom{n}{k}$ using finite calculus.

In know that $\Delta \binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{k-1}$, but this only works when k is constant.

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381920/sum-of-product-of-binomial-coefficients-sum-k-0n-1k-binomnk-binom) post might be related, although I was not able to understand how $\Delta^n \binom{n}{k}$ and $\sum _k (-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k}{n}$ are related.

Comment: What do you mean by "a simple formula"?  Formulas really don't get much simpler than $2^n$...

Comment: @lulu Oh I messed that one up. I edited it to what I wanted to say.

Comment: Well, again, $\sum_{k=0}^nk\binom nk$ has a simple expression, obtained by differentiating the binomial expansion of $(1+x)^n$.

Comment: I am aware of that, but I am searching for a way to solve this using finite calculus, because a method to do so could be useful in solving similar problems.